# Workaround for Chrome processing images within CSS multiple columns?

Tags: css, google-chrome, multiple-columns

Trying CSS multi-column layout, I found the latest Chrome 31 processes image content incorrectly:

```
body {
  column-count: 2;
}
```

[image: chrome scrrenshot]

Live example: http://dabblet.com/gist/7971645

There is no such a problem in Firefox which uses the space effectively.

Is there a workaround for Chrome making it behaving like Firefox in such case?

Comment: Interestingly, it works a lot better if you separate the flow text into paragraphs: http://dabblet.com/gist/7977042

Comment: Thank you! Using paragraphs plus disabling custom margins for nested elements gave me a working solution.